# How to create NSPasteboardWriting for Drag and Drop in NSCollectionView

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop, nscollectionview, nspasteboard

I have a one-section collection view and would like to implement Drag and Drop to allow reordering of the items. The `CollectionViewItem` has several textviews showing properties form my Parameter objects. Reading the doc I need to implement the `NSCollectionView` `delegate`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, pasteboardWriterForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSPasteboardWriting? {
    let parameter = parameterForIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath)
    return parameter // throws an error "Cannot convert return expression of type 'Parameter' to return type 'NSPasteboardWriting?'"
}
```

I have not found any information understandable for me describing the nature of the `NSPasteboardWriting` object. So, I have no idea how to proceed...
What is the `NSPasteboardWriting` object and what do I need to write in the pasteboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

*Disclaimer: I have struggled to find anything out there explaining this in a way that made sense to me, especially for Swift, and have had to piece the following together with a great deal of difficulty. If you know better, please tell me and I will correct it!*

The "pasteboardwriter" methods (such as the one in your question) must return something identifiable for the item about to be dragged, that can be written to a pasteboard. The drag and drop methods then pass around this pasteboard item.

Most examples I've seen simply use a string representation of the object. You need this so that in the `acceptDrop` method you can get your hands back on the originating object (the item being dragged). Then you can re-order that item's position, or whatever action you need to take with it.

Drag and drop involves four principal steps. I'm currently doing this with a sourcelist view, so I will use that example instead of your collection view.

1. in `viewDidLoad()` **register the sourcelist view to accept dropped objects**. Do this by telling it which pasteboard type(s) it should accept.

   `// Register for the dropped object types we can accept.
   sourceList.register(forDraggedTypes: [REORDER_SOURCELIST_PASTEBOARD_TYPE])`

   Here I'm using a custom type, `REORDER_SOURCELIST_PASTEBOARD_TYPE` that I define as a constant like so:

   ```
      `let REORDER_SOURCELIST_PASTEBOARD_TYPE = "com.yourdomain.sourcelist.item"`
   ```

   ...where the value is something unique to your app ie `yourdomain` should be changed to something specific to your app eg `com.myapp.sourcelist.item`.

   I define this outside any class (so it can be accessed from several classes) like so:

   ```
      import Cocoa

      let REORDER_SOURCELIST_PASTEBOARD_TYPE = "com.yourdomain.sourcelist.item"`

      class Something {
         // ...etc...
   ```
2. **implement the view's `pasteboardWriterForItem` method.** This varies slightly depending on the view you're using (i.e. sourcelist, collection view or whatever). For a sourcelist it looks like this:

   ```
     // Return a pasteboard writer if this outlineview's item should be able to 
     // drag-and-drop.
     func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, pasteboardWriterForItem item: Any) -> NSPasteboardWriting? {
       let pbItem = NSPasteboardItem()

       // See if the item is of the draggable kind. If so, set the pasteboard item.
       if let draggableThing = ((item as? NSTreeNode)?.representedObject) as? DraggableThing {
             pbItem.setString(draggableThing.uuid, forType: REORDER_SOURCELIST_PASTEBOARD_TYPE)
             return pbItem;
       }

       return nil
     }
   ```

   The most notable part of that is `draggableThing.uuid` which is simply a string that can uniquely identify the dragged object via its pasteboard.
3. **Figure out if your dragged item(s) can be dropped on the proposed item at the index given**, and if so, return the kind of drop that should be.

   ```
   func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, proposedItem item: Any?, proposedChildIndex index: Int) -> NSDragOperation {
       // Get the pasteboard types that this dragging item can offer. If none
       // then bail out.
       guard let draggingTypes = info.draggingPasteboard().types else {
           return []
       }

       if draggingTypes.contains(REORDER_SOURCELIST_PASTEBOARD_TYPE) {
           if index >= 0 && item != nil {
               return .move
           }
         }

         return []
       }
   ```
4. **Process the drop event.** Do things such as moving the dragged item(s) to their new position in the data model and reload the view, or move the rows in the view.

   ```
   func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, acceptDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, item: Any?, childIndex index: Int) -> Bool {
     let pasteboard = info.draggingPasteboard()

     let uuid = pasteboard.string(forType: REORDER_SOURCELIST_PASTEBOARD_TYPE)

     // Go through each of the tree nodes, to see if this uuid is one of them.
     var sourceNode: NSTreeNode?
     if let item = item as? NSTreeNode, item.children != nil {
       for node in item.children! {
           if let collection = node.representedObject as? Collection {
               if collection.uuid == uuid {
                   sourceNode = node
               }
           }
       }
     }

     if sourceNode == nil {
       return false
     }

     // Reorder the items.
     let indexArr: [Int] = [1, index]
     let toIndexPath = NSIndexPath(indexes: indexArr, length: 2)
     treeController.move(sourceNode!, to: toIndexPath as IndexPath)

     return true
   }
   ```

*Aside: The Cocoa mandate that we use pasteboard items for drag and drop seems very unnecessary to me --- why it can't simply pass around the originating (i.e. dragged) object I don't know! Obviously some drags originate outside the application, but for those that originate inside it, surely passing the object around would save all the hoop-jumping with the pasteboard.*

Comment: After a long time of recovering from pain I start trying to solve my still not working drag and drop issue. I do not understand what you mean with `let REORDER_SOURCELIST_PASTEBOARD_TYPE = "com.yourdomain.sourcelist.item"`. What is "yourdomain" and do I need to change it to something that fits to my app? What do you mean with "that I define outside my class..."? What do you mean with outside the class? Thanks

Comment: The `REORDER_SOURCELIST_PASTEBOARD_TYPE` needs to uniquely identify a custom type of pasteboard "thing", which in this case is the pasteboard item you're inventing to carry your drag-and-drop information. So yes, you're correct — change that to something unique to your app.

Comment: By "outside my class" I meant as an app-wide constant. Sorry for the confusion. I've updated my answer to hopefully clarify this.

Comment: collectionView.registerForDraggedTypes - rename in Swift 4

Answer (score 0):

The [NSPasteboardWriting](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboardwriting) protocol provides methods that [NSPasteboard](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard) (well, technically anyone, I guess) can use to generate different *representations* of an object for transferring around pasteboards, which is an older Apple concept that is used for copy/paste (hence *Paste*board) and, apparently, drag and drop in some cases.

It seems that, basically, a custom implementation of the protocol needs to implement methods that:

- tell what [UTI types](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html) (Apple's way of identifying file types [JPEG, GIF, TXT, DOCX, etc], similar to MIME-types—and that's a fun Google search ) your type can be transformed into

  - [writeableTypes(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboardwriting/1533578-writabletypes) & [writingOptions(forType:pasteboard:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboardwriting/1525372-writingoptions) to a lesser extent
- provide a representation of your class for each of the UTI types you claimed to support

  - [pasteboardPropertyList(forType:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboardwriting/1529482-pasteboardpropertylist)

The other answer provides a straightforward implementation of this protocol for use within a single app.

---

But practically?

> The Cocoa framework classes NSString, NSAttributedString, NSURL, NSColor, NSSound, NSImage, and NSPasteboardItem implement this protocol.

So if you've got a draggable item that can be completely represented as a URL (or String, or Color, or Sound, or Image, etc), just take the URL you have and cast it to `NSPasteboardWriting?`:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, pasteboardWriterForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSPasteboardWriting? {
    let url: URL? = someCodeToGetTheURL(for: indexPath) // or NSURL
    return url as NSPasteboardWriting?
}
```

This is not helpful if you have a complicated type, but I hope it's helpful if you have a collection view of images or some other basic item.